# Kafka consumer retrieve data using offset

Tags: apache-kafka

1. While writing data into Kafka Producer can I get offset of the record
2. Can I use the same offset and partition to retrieve  specific record

Please share example if you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send a record to Kafka, in order to know the offset and the partition assigned to such a record you can use one of the overloaded versions of the `send` method. There is the one with a `Callback` parameter which expose the `onCompletion` method which provides you a `RecordMetadata` instance with the information you want.

You can take a look at the Kafka Producer API for that here :

https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html

From a consumer side, if you want to recover a specific record starting a specific offset, you can use the `assign` method (instead of `subscribe`) in order to have the consumer being assigned to a specific partition and then you can use `seek` for specifying the offset. Pay attention that the consumer won't receive just one record but all the records starting from that offset.

For this info see the Kafka Consumer API as well.

https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Comment: thank you. I will test and post the comments tomorrow. but is there a way to retrieve only the record for which the offset is provided

Comment: the consumer configuration provides the max.poll.records parameter which is 500 by default. Somehow you could use it but then you'll have a consumer good for reading 1 record at time each poll so I don't think it's a good solution but it depends on your use case, so it could work. In that case after seek and calling poll you will get the only record at that offset. Btw if you call poll another time, you'll receive the next one. It's the way how Kafka consumer works.